# QuickSight: problem with calculated field when using minus operator

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I have a weird problem in Quicksight with an easy task.

I need to subtract from a constant a calculated field. Something like this:

```
 7 - ({createdDate_dayOfWeek})
```

I have problems with this simple formula because of the minus operator. Imagine that {createdDate_dayOfWeek}=7. When I perform

```
 7 - ({createdDate_dayOfWeek})
```

the result is 2!!

But when I perform this operation

```
 7 + ({createdDate_dayOfWeek})
```

the output is 14 (what I expected).

Has anyone had a problem like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar experiences with quicksight calculated fields. One solution that has worked for me is to store the constant as a calculated, and then use that field in the calculation you're describing above.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll try the solution but I'd like to understand why Quicksight works in this way,